# Uses of category-theory

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

I am a graduate student currently working my way through an introductory course in category theory.

A question I have for this theory is why it is usefull?

Now i know this is a rich theory that is being used in many fields in mathematics, for example we have encountered categorical notions in a (introductory) course of algebraic geometry. Here we defined a contravariant functor between the categories of k-varieties (with k an algebraically closed field) and the category of k-algebras with their respective morphisms.

However we did work with the *notions* of category-theory, we didn't use any specific theorems.

So to specify my question further: *In what way does the work done in category theory help us in proving important theorems in other fields in mathematics?* Or perhaps: *Can you provide examples in which deep categorical theorems are applicable and usefull for proving hard problems in other fields of mathematics?*

Any criticism on my way of posing this quesion is welcomed, this is my first post here!

Comment: Possibly related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29152/motivation-and-use-for-category-theory?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810706/examples-of-useful-category-theory-results?rq=1

Comment: And also on MO : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19325/most-striking-applications-of-category-theory

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208375/honest-application-of-category-theory?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312605/what-is-category-theory-useful-for?noredirect=1&lq=1(I can't edit my other comments). I'll stop throwing links now, but I thought it would be useful to connect the question to all these.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016549/what-are-the-important-properties-that-categories-are-really-abstracting/

Comment: @ArnaudD. Keep going. The question is a (multi-) duplicate anyway.